# Как вытащить определённые данные из ответа от github api

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, requests

Вот код:

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/repos/NAME/TEST/contents/', timeout=1)
print(response.content)
```

В итоге я получаю примерно вот такой ответ:

```
b'[{"name":"009.version","path":"009.version","sha"...
```

И мне нужно как то вытащить 009.version

Я пытался сделать так:

```
print(response.content['name'])
```

Но увы это не работает : (

Comment: `response.json()[0]['name']`

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На основе совета [@andreymal](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178213/andreymal) в [комментарии](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1210274/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%be%d1%82-github-api#comment2114848_1210274).

В ответ вы получаете объект `response`, содержащий данные в формате JSON. Для того, что бы получить их в виде структуры данных python, нужно сделать так:

```py
>>> data = response.json()[0]
```

Дальше можно обращаться к данной переменной, как к словарю. Например, для получения свойства `'name'`:

```py
>>> print(data['name'])
"009.version"
```

Comment: Всё отлично работает, спасибо!